# pyspark how to collect map keys into list

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with a map column. I want to collect the not null keys into a new column:

[image: P1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [map_filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_filter.html) to filter the non null keys and then use [map_keys](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.map_keys.html) which returns the keys as an array.